# gradle: how to suppress "* What went wrong:", "* Try:" messages

Tags: java, gradle

Gradle shows "* What went wrong:", "* Try:" messages every failed testing.

```
$ gradle test -q

2 tests completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/gradle/app/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I want to show only:

```
2 tests completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

How can I suppress this hint messages?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's almost intolerable seeing all that crap clutter up the output window, causing actual helpful text to scroll up out of view. Who thought putting all that crap in there with no way to suppress it was a good idea?

Comment: If you use IntelliJ, I think I may have found a way around this nuisance when running tests from the IDE: Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle->"Run tests using:" - Select IntelliJ IDEA instead of Gradle.

Comment: Got no answer here either.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891929/control-gradle-error-logging-at-end-of-build

Comment: Still no answer for this? Bummer.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up following Gradle's guide on [creating custom event logger](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html#sec:changing_what_gradle_logs)

I created this file `customlogger.gradle.kts`

```
useLogger(CustomEventLogger())

class CustomEventLogger() : BuildAdapter(), TaskExecutionListener {
    override fun beforeExecute(task: Task) { }
    override fun afterExecute(task: Task, state: TaskState) { }
    override fun buildFinished(result: BuildResult) {
        if (result.failure != null) {
            println("Build completed with errors".red)
        } else {
            println("Build completed".green)
        }
    }

    val String.red: String get() { return "\u001b[31m$this\u001b[0m" }
    val String.green: String get() { return "\u001b[32m$this\u001b[0m" }
}
```

then I run:

```
supervisor -n exit -x gradle -- -I ./customlogger.gradle.kts test
```

Everything is as clean as it should be now (except for that last line. ugh)

[image]